# What's the meaning of the partial derivatives of B-spline as given by scipy.interpolate.bisplev?

Tags: numpy, scipy, interpolation, scientific-computing

I have a mesh generated from cloudpoint, which could be described as `z = f(x,y)`, so I'm using `scipy.interpolate.bisplrep` and `bisplev`, with good results.

`bisplev` can be used with parameters `dx=n` and/or `dy=n` so that the results are derivatives of order `n` at the evaluated points. I plan to use this to calculate mean and gaussian curvatures (called `surfature` in Matlab), and that should involve getting the second-order partial derivatives of the survace

The results using one of the partial derivatives at a time, say `dx` are great, clearly representing the gradient as a "shading" effect, as seen in this image from a human back (code first):

```
    self.spline = inter.bisplrep(self.pointlist[:,1],
                                 self.pointlist[:,0],
                                 self.pointlist[:,2], s=smoothing_factor)
    self.mesh_shadow = inter.bisplev(yy.flat, xx.flat, self.spline, dy=1)
```

[image]

So far, so good. The problem is: I can't understand (and can't find any explanation) what's the meaning of the result when I ask for **both partial derivatives at the same time**, since there isn't any obvious numeric or visual meaning. For example, if I use `dx` AND `dy`:

```
self.mesh_shadow = inter.bisplev(yy.flat, xx.flat, self.spline, dx=1, dy=1)
```

I get this:
[image]

So, I wonder:

1. What's the mathematical/geometrical meaning of the simultaneous result of first-order partial derivatives of a surface as given by `bislplev(..., dx=1, dy=1)`, if any?
2. Would there be a way to get the maximum slope (in any direction) from `bislplev(..., dx=1, dy=1)`?
3. Are both partial derivatives supposed to be called together, in the first place? I see I can use, say, `(..., dx=1, dy=2)` and the function seems to produce "valid" results, but would that make any sense?

Every time, the returned value is a (Y,X)-shaped array of single float values (Z or one of its derivative-related values).

Any help?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The partial derivative you get with dx=n, dy=m is the mathematical object (or rather, its numerical approximation)

   (d/dx)^n (d/dy)^m f(x,y)
2. You cannot compute the Gaussian curvature just from dx=2,dy=0 and dx=0,dy=2 --- you in general also need also the cross-derivative dx=1,dy=1.
3. Partial derivatives (d/dx)^n (d/dy)^m f(x,y) are mathematically well-defined. With splines, if you go to too high orders, you should start getting zeros or discontinuities.

Comment: I'll have to study your points, they seem very valuable and just what I needed. Excelent point in d2 discontinuity, because I am using third order splines, and I've read they are guaranteed to be differentiable just until a few orders (two?). Thanks!